# Debugging not working via SQL Developer tool

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am executing the stored procedure for debugging, but it is not properly working.

- Oracle version: Oracle 9i
- SQL Developer Tool Version -  Version 3.2.20.09

DBA provided to grant access to debugging:

[image]

The debugger accepted the connection from the database on port 56305.
above this line not came. Kindly suggest how to fix it ?

Comment: You are using a database that was released over 20 years ago and went out of extended support over 10 years ago and a version of SQL Developer that is 20 versions before the current version. Maybe it is time to upgrade?

Comment: @MT0 Database version can't change, so if sql developer version changes then is it working?

Comment: Did you recompile your PL/SQL unit after those compile parameters are set?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle port is 1521. Except for the new debugging interface. This allocates additional tcp connection on dynamic port. Most likely your DB is beyond FW and this port is closed.